# How to make automatically scroll down a div tag on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Cannot make a div element automatically scroll down.

```
$('#div').scrollTop(1000)
```

This doesn't work, but if set on click it works:

```
$('btn').click(function()
{
    $('#div').scrollTop(1000);
});
```

I need it to scroll down without clicking any button. What do I need to change?

Comment: window.onload? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload

Comment: Tried window.onload = function() {...} but doesn't seem to fix this

Comment: @Root149: Then you need to supply more context, or a runnable example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Fixed. I was foolishly using scrollTop before an ajax request which is supposed to fill up the div tag. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running it after the document is ready:

```
$(function() { // short for $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#div').scrollTop(1000);
});
```

Chances are you're running your script before the element exists (check `$('#div').length` -- if it's `0`, you're running it too soon). You need to wait until the DOM is loaded, which wrapping your code in the above will handle.

Comment: It may actually be, since I'm using Ajax to add content to the div tag, thanks

Comment: Yeah, the issue was that the scrollTop was before the Ajax request, so it first scrolled down an empty div tag and then added data. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#div').scrollTop(1000);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#div').scrollTop(1000);
});
```